# the class existed in both location asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework

I am creating a website using asp.net with entity framework 6.0.

and I always get the same error:

> The type 'Quran_Project.Auth' exists in both 'c:\Users\Samy
>   Sammour\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\vs\e4eda6ba\583ea773\App_Code.bn6fnxuc.dll' and 'c:\Users\Samy
>   Sammour\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\vs\e4eda6ba\583ea773\assembly\dl3\9806d343\aaa99a3b_ef81d101\Quran
>   Project.DLL'

I have been trying for more than three days, and till now I got no solution.

I cleaned the project and rebuild it again, and also put :

`<compilation batch="false">`

but nothing works, please if you may help me I will appreciate it.
thank you

P.S. I use VS2013

Comment: use some tool for example ccleaner or just go to http://metadataconsulting.blogspot.com/2011/08/how-to-clear-windows-7-temporary-files.html and follow the tutorial. Or just go to c:\Users\Samy Sammour\AppData\Local\Temp\ and delete your temponary files... there are not important and they are TEMPONARY

Comment: I got the same error nothing works

Comment: Please don't ever suggest a cleanup program. Those cause more trouble than help. The temporary ASP.NET folder in the error list is the key. If you have had settings differently, the code may have been compiled to separate files and then to a single one. Delete those files. If that doesn't help your compilation settings are messed up and need a check.

Comment: I did and clean both but every time i run the iis again it will create the two files again and will cause the same problem

Comment: I guess the problem is with the compiling

Comment: I'm with Sami here, the Clean operation can sometimes have some very unwanted side affects.

Comment: I have deleted my suggestion about cleanup, I was doing it my self with this kind of error when my two solutions was using my same assembly but name was different and it cached it. I did cleanup many times always without errors, but I have no idea why you suggest not to. I can understand on Windows Server but? Any example?

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you've renamed the Assembly at any point. I usually recommend going into the `/bin/debug/` folder and deleting it's contents. Then perform a rebuild.